# MessageDialog with no border in gtk

Tags: c, gtk

I am currently developping an application in c using gtk and I am facing a problem with the MessageDialog widget display. It does almost exactly what I want : It pops up but there is no border displayed around the MessageDialog... (and it is not really visible on the screen). I am searching now for a while on how find a way to add this border but i haven't found anything yet...

Here is the simple code I am using :

```
GtkWidget *dialog;

dialog = gtk_message_dialog_new (window_main,
                             GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT,
                             GTK_MESSAGE_ERROR,
                             GTK_BUTTONS_CLOSE,
                             "My message");
gtk_dialog_run (GTK_DIALOG (dialog));
gtk_widget_destroy (dialog);
```

Here is an image of the problem (the red label is on the background, there is no border between the dialog and this label) : [Image](http://imageshack.us/a/img841/8476/messagedialognoborder.jpg)

Did anyone already face this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how it can both lack a border and be invisible, your wording is not very clear there.

Still, did you try adding a call to

```
gtk_widget_show_all(dialog);
```

before running the dialog?

Comment: At first thanks for your answer.

Sorry if my first message wasn't clear. (I tried to post with a picture to illustrate the problem but I can't because of my lack of reputation).

The messageDialog is visible : Label + Error Image + Button Close. But there is no border around the Dialog.

Comment: Here is a image of the problème : http://imageshack.us/a/img841/8476/messagedialognoborder.jpg (I hope it helps to understand my issue). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem came from the fact that I didn't use a window manager on my device.